# introduction to hamiltonian actions and moment maps.

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, moment-map

I'm trying to find some good articles or books to learn about moment maps and hamiltonian actions. I ddo have some basic differential geometry (and representation theory) knowledge, but not really symplectic geometry. This is to read up for my bachelor project, since I'll be working towards the duistermaat heckmann formula.  Could anyone provide me some titles or links? Thank you .

Comment: I like Chris Woodward's notes, but he does cover a lot more than just the topics you've asked about.

Answer (score 2):

Moment Maps and Combinatorial Invariants of Hamiltonian Tn-spaces, by V. Guillemin.

Lectures on Symplectic Geometry Ana Cannas da Silva.

Comment: Thank you. Are there specific chapters i should read from da silva? Or everything?

Comment: Do you perhaps have less advanced suggestions? The book by Guilleminis too advanced and it assumes the reader has some knowledge on symplectic geometry.